# by changing the selection of radio button now working fine

Tags: javascript, html, css

if first time I want to select or changing the radio button I want to change the label color to red, but it not working perfectly, I use a on change function inside radio button

```
<script>
    function changecolor(){
      document.getElementsByClassName("label").style.color='red'
    }
  </script>
<body>
<div class="group">
  <label for="one" class="label">Select Any</label>
    <div class="input">
     <input id="one" class="radio" name="radio-group" type="radio" onchange="changecolor()" >
      <input id="one" class="radio" name="radio-group" type="radio" onchange="changecolor()">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName return an htmlcollection
so you have two solutions to make work your code

- iterate on each element of the htmlcollection and apply the style
- or use an index for access one of the specific element

```js
function changecolor(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].style.color='red'
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label for="one" class="label">Select Any</label>
    <div class="input">
     <input id="one" class="radio" name="radio-group" type="radio" onchange="changecolor()" >
      <input id="one" class="radio" name="radio-group" type="radio" onchange="changecolor()">
   </div>
</div>
```